# Guest user causes 'Shell Infrastructure Host has stopped working' messages

Tags: windows-10

I'm running Windows 10, 64 bit, and whenever someone tries to use the guest account, nothing loads and the following error is displayed on the screen: `Shell Infrastructure Host has stopped working`

I logged in as an Administrator and checked the event viewer to find out what is going on, this is what comes up:

[image: Event Viewre]

The application that matches `{8BC3F05E-D86B-11D0-A075-00C04FB68820}` is Windows Management and Instrumentation.

I tried to look it up on Google but nothing seems relevant.

Comment: follow this in the admin account: http://pastebin.com/tU3Agf5M and import it. Go to the guest account an wait for a crash. go back to the admin account, zip, the dmp and share it (oneDrive)

Comment: @magicandre1981, Registry edited, crash happened, nothing was dumped.

Comment: try this generic one which captures dmp files of all processes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r3re0uvlcg2dqsc/WER.reg?dl=0

Comment: @magicandre1981, nada :(

Comment: download procdump (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) and register it as post mortem debugger from the admin account (**procdump -ma -i C:\dumps**). Look if this generates dumps for the guest account

Comment: does procdump work or still not?

Comment: @magicandre1981, yes! it generated 2 .dmp files: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18969413/Dumps.zip (sorry for the delay, I had power supply issues with another machine)

Comment: have you uploaded the wrong files? I only see 2 dumps of Tiworker.exe But I can see that you use a Font improvement tool (MacType), remove it and look if this fixes the crashes.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Removed and it didn't fix anything. I tried to log off and log on again to the Guest account and all I get in Dumps is Tiworker.exe dumps.

Comment: I'll ask Andrew Richards (co author of procdump) why the tool doesn't capture the crash dumps and post here I he replies

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'll stay tuned

Comment: ok, Andrew suggests to check the fodler permissions of the dump folder and look if guests have full write permissions. if this is ok, open eventlog, filter for the shellexperience host crashes and export them into an EVTX file

Comment: @magicandre1981, evtx file here: dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18969413/errors.evtx

Comment: I only see some DCOM errors and no shellexperiencehost entries. So no wonder, that no dump is generated.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Yeah, I found a correlation between the `Shell Infrastructure Host has stopped working` errors and the DCOM errors in the event viewer, that's what I tried to explain in the OP :P

Comment: I don't see a correlation. Export all errors from the Jan 1st 2016 till today.

Comment: @magicandre1981, that's impossible, when I try to create this view the event viewer says `Event Viewer cannot open the event log or custom view. Verify that Event Log serivce is running or queiry is too long. (13)`

Comment: export all entries. I'll filter them on my own.

Comment: @magicandre1981, here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18969413/events.evtx THANKS A LOT

Comment: after logging into the guest account, run ProcExplorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) as with your admin account permissions. When you now see the **Shell Infrastructure Host has stopped working** error, go to ProcExp, rightclick on shellexphost.exe and create a full dump. Does this work?

Comment: @magicandre1981, yup. Here's the dump: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18969413/ShellExperienceHost.dmp may I know how are you analyzing it? With WinDbg?

Comment: I can't see any crash data in the dump. use the snipping tool to generate a screenshot of the error message that you see when shellexphost crashes.

Comment: Here's the screenshot http://imgur.com/Uw5E9md

Comment: was the shellexphost restarted before you captured the dump? when you get thismessage, don't click it away, use ALT-Tab to go to ProcExplorer and generate the dmp. After you did this, you can click on "close program"

Comment: That must be the relevant dump: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18969413/sihost.dmp

Comment: ok, this time I see some crash info, but with the public debug data that MS provides I can't see what is wrong. I've asked Andrew again for help.

Comment: you get an Access Denied error. Andrew needs a Processmonitor trace (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx), run Procmon as admin in the guest accout, when you get the crash, go to procmon, stop the trace and save it (unfiltered) as PML. Share this PML file.

Comment: were you able to capture a ProcMon trace when you get this crash?

Comment: @magicandre1981, Yup, it weights 600MB so I guess this link will be available in an hour from now: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18969413/Logfile.PML Sorry for the delay, I had some other, urgent, issues

Comment: ok, I submitted the PML to Andrew.

Comment: @magicandre1981, any news from Andrew?

Comment: he only showed me how he saw that error in the dmp. I asked him if the PML was helpful, but I haven't heard anything about this from him. If this is really a critical issue for you, contact the MS support via phone and open a support case.